# ¿como puedo graficar la cantidad de valores faltantes en cada variable con ggplot?

Tags: rstudio, ggplot2, null, visualización-de-datos

Intento realizar un grafico con ggplot2 que represente la cantidad de valores nulos de cada variable, similar al siguiente pero con `ggplot2`:

```
paquetes_cran <- readr::read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cienciadedatos/datos-de-miercoles/master/datos/2019/2019-07-03/paquetes_CRAN.csv")

library(DataExplorer) 
plot_missing(paquetes_cran)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido federico hector herrera a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Por favor agrega el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta ahora, aun si no ha funcionado, es importante para que te pregunta sea bien recibida, sino puede mal interpretarse como que estás pidiendo que resolvamos una tarea o un asignación.

Answer (score 0):

para poder hacer una gráfica equivalente es necesario hacer un procesamiento de la base de datos. Te dejo acá una opción de cómo podría hacerse con tidyverse.

```
# Importar los datos 
paquetes_cran <- readr::read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cienciadedatos/datos-de-miercoles/master/datos/2019/2019-07-03/paquetes_CRAN.csv")

# Procesar la base
df_na <- paquetes_cran              %>% 
    mutate_all(.funs = ~is.na(.))   %>% # Evaluar si la observación es un NA
    summarise_all(.funs = ~sum(.))  %>% # Sumar todos los NAs de la variable
    # Cambiar formato de ancho a largo para facilitar la vizualización 
    pivot_longer(
        cols = everything(), 
        names_to = "Features", 
        values_to = "Missing_Rows"
    )

# Graficar }
ggplot(df_na, 
       aes(x = Missing_Rows, y = reorder(Features, desc(Missing_Rows)))) +
    geom_col() +
    geom_label(aes(label = Missing_Rows))
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).